# Unable to group data in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Id | MenuName      | vc_Link | SubMenu1 | IsMainMenu | TypeOfMenu
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Home          |  NULL   |  NULL    |     1      |     0
2  | Projects      |  NULL   |  NULL    |     1      |     0
4  | Pr1           |  NULL   |   2      |     0      |     1
5  | Homesub       |  NULL   |   1      |     0      |     1
6  | Pr1Sub1       |  NULL   |   4      |     0      |     2
```

The above is my table structure.

1. MenuName is names of menus and submenus
2. SubMenu1 is that submenus belong to a paticular menu whos id is saved as submenu1
3. MainMenu is a bit to know whether it is a menu or submenu.
4. typeofmenu is that

> ```
> 0 means main menu
> 1 means submenu
> 2 means submenu's submenu
> ```

Now my problem is i want to display it as below

```
   1 Home
      5 HomeSub
   2 Projects
     4 Pr1
         6 Pr1Sub1

   Id | MenuName      | vc_Link | SubMenu1 | IsMainMenu | TypeOfMenu
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | Home          |  NULL   |  NULL    |     1      |     0
    5  | HomeSub       |  NULL   |  1       |     0      |     1
    2  | Projects      |  NULL   |  NULL    |     1      |     0
    4  | Pr1           |  NULL   |   2      |     0      |     1
    6  | Pr1Sub1       |  NULL   |   4      |     0      |     2
```

How to group like this?
Only after grouping like this i can make the result of this query as a tree structure showing menus and its submenus.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008 R2..

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
with menu_tree (id, menuname, level, sort_path) as (
   select id, 
          cast(menuname as varchar(max)), 
          1 as level,
          cast(id as varchar(max)) as sort_path
   from menus
   where submenu1 is null
   union all
   select m.id, 
          cast(replicate('_', p.level * 2) + m.menuname as varchar(max)) as menuname, 
          p.level + 1,
          p.sort_path + '_' + cast(m.id as varchar(max))
   from menus m
     join menu_tree p on p.id = m.submenu1
)  
select id, menuname
from menu_tree
order by sort_path;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c4ba/1

Comment: I use sql server 2008 r2...can you please tell me how to convert this ANSI query to sql server 2008 query

Comment: error:  Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "menuname" of recursive query "menu_tree".

Comment: I changed a little because concat doesn't work out with sql      with menu_tree as (
   select id, menuname, 1 as level
   from menus
   where submenu1 is null
   union all
   select m.id, replicate(' ', p.level * 2)+ m.menuname as menuname, p.level + 1 
   from menus m
     join menu_tree p on p.id = m.submenu1
)  
select id, menuname
from menu_tree;